# Какую Azure VM выбрать для сервиса?

Tags: linux, администрирование, windows-server, azure

Привет всем.

Есть проект, по нагрузке примерно такой же как и хэшкод(публикации, комментарии, профили ect).
Вчера получил подписку BizSpark. Не секрет, что 150$ в месяц дается. Так вот, какой тариф на Azure мне выбрать на 150 долларов?

Варианты:

1. Basic - Серия A - А3 - 4 ядра - 7гб ОЗУ - 130$/ month.
2. Standart - Серия D - D2 - 2 ядра - 7гб ОЗУ - SSD 100 ГБ - 126$/ month

По-моему, больше нет вариантов. Выбирал, конечно, из Linux, вдруг кто подумал про Windows Server - . -
В любом случае остается 15-20$, как их на Azure лучше заюзать?

P.S. All back-end is on Node.js
Помогите советом, пожалуйста, поделитесь опытом. )

Comment: @Влад Тимофеев, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Ну, как мне кажется, варианта А3 хватит за глаза на первое время. Вообще для достижения SLA 99.95% необходимо парраллельно использовать 2 машины. Так что бери лучше 2 машины А2. И не забудьте запилить скалируемую архитектуру иначе Azure и не нужен (больше денег будет жрать, чем пользы давать). Оставшиеся 15-20$ оставь на всякий случай как подушку безопасности. К примеру для того, чтобы эксперименты проводить с другими машинами или на базы данных (Azure SQL).

Как по мне, то если есть возможность, то надо использовать PaaS, если возможно. Таким образом экономили бы время на управление серверами, но есть и свои ограничения. То бишь веб- или рабочие-роли. Лучше всего перед созданием приложения почитай книжку Cloud Architecture Patterns от Bill Wilder: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023777.do